# I want to schedule email (date, time is in database->table) wp_schedule_event() not working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, email, table

I want to schedule email (date, time is in database->table) wp_schedule_event() not working, I want to send emails to clients on future different dates and times from database, I am developing plugin myself, Help me.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's not working? Are you getting errors? Are the jobs running but failing to send emails, or not running? Are they still in the 'cron' entry in wp_options? Are your site's cron jobs running regularly - are you getting enough traffic to run them at the right times, or do you have a system cron job set up to trigger WordPress cron, or something else?

Comment: wp cron job ain't working while no one is on website.

Comment: Right, yes, that's normal. See [Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) and [Hooking WP-Cron into the system task scheduler](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/) from the WordPress documentation. Or if you search "wordpress system cron" there are plenty of other instructions that will do this for you, or even plugins and system daemons you can use for high volume or long-lived cron jobs.